# WPF TextBox Height Equals Parent Height minus 50 pixels?

Tags: wpf, textbox, height

I'm successfully getting a TextBox to resize with a parent Border height but I need the TextBox to actually be 50 pixels smaller in height than the parent Border.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

The code I'm using is

```
<Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
     <TextBox x:Name="txtActivityNotes" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can't you just set a bottom margin of 50?

```
<TextBox Margin="0,0,0,50" />
```

Answer (score 6):

I've tried following and it works.
add following to text box in xaml:

```
------
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, *AncestorType*={x:Type *Grid*}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
------
```

Here, AncestorType is type of container containing the textBox. In my case it was 'Grid'.
And also add margin like,

```
  Margin="0,0,0,50"
```

to keep distance from border below.

============

oops sorry i posted on the same page.!

Answer (score 2):

how about using a converter on the binding to minus 50 off the height

[heres an example of using a converter](http://blogs.msdn.com/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx)

Comment: Hi Aran, I had considered using a converter but it seemed a bit overkill just to adjust a value by 50! I'm using converters elsewhere for visibility etc but I was hoping for a simpler solution if one exists...

Comment: converters are normal way in wpf. yes margin would work in this particular case but converter valid soultion too. and is only way in many cases.